# Current location is not showing in my android app

Tags: android

I have written code for getting current location in android project. But it is not picking my location automatically and showing marker somewhere in the world although I'm sitting in Pakistan.

**Map Activity code is here**

```
 package com.example.uber;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class MapsActivity2 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private LocationListener locationListener;

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        }
        /**
         * Manipulates the map once available.
         * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
         * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
         * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
         * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
         * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
         */
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Log.d("Location", location.toString());

                    mMap.clear();
                    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                    LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                    //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLocation).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newLocation));

                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
       try{
           List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);

           if(addressList != null && addressList.size()>0){
               Log.d("Address",addressList.get(0).toString());
           }else {
               Log.d("Address","Couldn't find Address");
           }
       }catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            };
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    Activity#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

                    //   return;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            } else {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Ask for permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

                } else {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                }
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Manifiest Permisions**
I have given following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**My actual location is**
31.175669, 74.104891

I have manually set my location in extended control of emulator.as shown in figure. But I want's that my code pick my location dynamically please help me
[Android emulator image with extended control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOyzS.png)

Comment: Try testing your app in physical device.

Comment: Use a real mobile phone for testing. so that it will get your current location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue. When you test your app in AVD map will show google corporation as your place. But if your code is correct, when you test the app in your device, you will get your current location correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your Android emulator doesn't use your real location. Most of the times the location is set in the Emulator settings, like in Android Studio.

Use a real device for testing, or open the settings to change your location.

You can find more information about the emulator here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator