# navigator.geolocation giving wrong current position in android app webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I'm using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to get the location with `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude`, the function that calculates this is used in an android app through a webview.
The problem is when I test this function in a browser it gives me the correct location and when I test it in android app it's giving to me another location (I think it's default location or older location of the device).

My gradle is this one:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: See correct answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483232/