# FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation always returns null(android 6.0,api 23)

Tags: java, android, geo

I try it on my cell phone. It always returns null. Why?(all permissions were granted.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location: "+location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

            });
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Current location is not showing in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483232/current-location-is-not-showing-in-my-android-app)

Comment: unfortunately i still can't get my current location on my cell phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is never a guarantee that you get a location from `getLastLocation()`. Usually that means that nothing that no application has used the GPS to get your location so there is nothing cached.

Typically all you have to do is open google maps or something that a location will be cached once it has a lock

Comment: thanks, how can i get current location without going to google maps and without last location?

Comment: you have to start listening for location changes through the location client