# My current location is not clear in Google map Android

Tags: android

I use Google map in my app. I try to get my current location I can show my location but the point is not clear. I don't Know what is problem .
As you can see picture below.

[image]

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
        String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know solution that ?

Comment: This should work. Zoom in and out see if gets clear. See if your Internet is working and Google Map API in not blocked. You can also try on a physical device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current location will not work correctly in emulator. [Current location is not showing in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483232/current-location-is-not-showing-in-my-android-app/60483980#60483980) You should try it in actual device to get correct result. For focus in or out you may use this code:

```
mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(mylocation).title("My Location"))
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation, 14f))
```

You can change 14f to what you want.

Comment: Hi brother, can you  look here if you have some tiem. Maybe you have  answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542209/how-can-intent-or-pass-data-through-on-click-image-in-slider-layout-android