# Why my current location on Google Maps is incorrect in Android app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want to make an Android app which determines my location on map. I used the Google Maps SDK documentation and code from there.

The problem is I always get Google headquarters as my current location instead of my real.

What can be wrong? Below is my code.

```
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private CameraPosition mCameraPosition;

    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;

    private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        getDeviceLocation();
    }
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        try {
             if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                               mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                               if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
                                   LatLng mLocation = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                           mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                                   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLocation).title("You are here"));
                                   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLocation));
                               }
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                        .newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (SecurityException e)  {
                Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: See my answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483232/current-location-is-not-showing-in-my-android-app/60483980#60483980

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Current location is not showing in my android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483232/current-location-is-not-showing-in-my-android-app)

Answer (score 2):

You might be using an emulator. That's mostly the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483232/current-location-is-not-showing-in-my-android-app/60483980#60483980

Comment: Marked as duplicate